# use for loop in jquery remove index, it can't remove completely, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/SdHLZ/

use for loop in jquery remove index, it can't remove completely, why?
below code if only do console.log() will see 4 element, but if uncomment remove line , it won't work

I do test in each function sure it work.

```
$('.button').on('click', 'input', function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < $('.list').length; i++) {

    // $('.list').get(i).remove();
    // console.log($('.list').get(i));
  }
});
```

Comment: Because after you've deleted 0th element they shift. Why not just `$('.list').remove()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to remove all the `.list` elements, you do not need a loop. You can simply call `.remove()` on the selector and jQuery will take care of finding the elements for you:

```
$('.button').on('click', 'input', function() {
    $('.list').remove();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SdHLZ/2/)

To remove only elements where there is no content, use `filter()`:

```
$('.button').on('click', 'input', function() {
    $('.list').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).text() == '';
    }).remove();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SdHLZ/3/)

Comment: thanks for reply actually I want to remove some list content == ''

Comment: So you only want to remove `.list` elements where there is no content - is that correct?

Comment: Thanks,  wondering I can't use for loop when delete index, that will shift. so if I use each set if statement or this method which is faster

Comment: I've not tested, but I would expect this method to be faster than `each()`.